# How come i get a syntax error code 1 in this simple sqlite query

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I've got an sqlite query that goes like this :

```
String sql_group = "CREATE TABLE group(id VARCHAR(25),name VARCHAR(25),account_id VARCHAR(25));"
```

And when i do :

```
db.execSQL(sql_group);
```

it makes a FATAL ERROR, i've got a syntax error code 1 while compiling this.

I don't see what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because `GROUP`, which is the name of your table, is a Reserved Keyword. You still use it but you need to escape it with `brackets`,

```
String sql_group = "CREATE TABLE [group](id VARCHAR(25), ...";
```

- [SQLite Keywords (*includes ways to escape keywords*)](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

But I suggest that you should avoid using such names to avoid problem on the future.

Answer (score 2):

You have used [group](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) for table name, but this is SQL operator :) Just use another word

Answer (score 0):

you can used this way.

```
String table_creation="CREATE TABLE test_Table +" (" +
        " id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        " name TEXT NOT NULL , " + 
        " address TEXT , " + 
        " city TEXT)";
```

Now you can used this **table_creation** for creating table.

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Comment: why give -1,this is syntax for sqlite table creation.

Comment: And what is the difference to the question's `CREATE TABLE` statement? The different column names aren't useful.

Comment: It may not be the solution i was looking for, but for naming of table it's good, you will have no problem (I used group and transaction for my app, which both are restricted)